# How to iterate through dictionary whose value field is list in c#?

Tags: c#

I have `Dictionary<Key, IList<Days>> days` that needs to be iterated through in foreach loop so I can convert it to `Dictionary<Key, IList<string>> days2`;
I tried using following but compiler does not like it (Cannot convert to element type.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,IList<Days>> kvp in days)
{
//do stuff
}
```

How do you foreach through dictionary key value pair whose value is list?
If possible I am trying to avoid using linq to make it more readable.

Comment: How is your variable days defined?

Comment: You can use the [ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) method to perform the conversion.

Comment: `Dictionary<SomeType, IList<Days>>` days

Comment: @Robert The problem is days' value IList<Days> Days is an enum, but the days2' IList<string>. Which I have a method that converts string to Days enum. DaysHelper.ToDaysEnum(string)

Comment: Your method can be included in the lamba expression for the  `Func<TSource, TKey>` parameter, as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [implicitly typed local variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) instead of specifying the type precisely. It's done using `var` keyword:

```
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{

}
```

You can also use LINQ to get desired `Dictionary<Key, IList<string>>`:

```
Dictionary<Key, IList<string>> dict2 =
    dict.ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                      x => (IList<String>)x.Value.Select(y => y.ToString()).ToList());
```

Replace simple `ToString()` call with `Days` to `string` conversion you'd like to use.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about var but for some reason I did not think about using it here. It works like magic. I ended up having 2 foreach loop, the inside one iterating over each list element and then saving it to another list with converted values and then once inside foreach is done I save that with the key and add to the converting list.

Answer (score 2):

You have the dictionary defined as `Dictionary<Key, IList<Days>>` which means you should match those types in the foreach loop:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Key, IList<Days>> kvp in days)
{
    foreach (Days day in kvp.Value)
    {
        // Convert individual elements
    }
}
```

Your other option would be to convert using the `ToDictionary` extension method:

```
days.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => Value.Select(d => d.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string,IList<Days>> kvp in days)
{
    IList<Days> dayList = kvp.Value;
    // TODO: convert and insert in new dictionary
}
```

Comment: foreach(KeyValuePair<string,IList<Days>> kvp in days) this is the part that I am having problem with compiler error. foreach does not like having list in dictionary. using var worked though.

Comment: You are still missing the second '>' in your foreach loop

Comment: Ya my bad that was a typo. Actually I do have that in my original code and you still will get compile error.